# Deletar input dinâmico

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou usando javascript para criar inputs dinamicamente. Crio um input de telefone e email dessa forma.

Eu criei uma função deleteEmail() que deleta o mais recente criado, no entanto quando eu crio outros campos eu perco a referência de qual deletar

O que eu quero saber é como eu deleto esses inputs criados usando JS puro?

```
 function addEmail(){
    var container = document.getElementById("box");
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var btn_delete = document.createElement("button");
    var br = document.createElement("br");

    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "email";

    label.innerText = "Email";
    label.htmlFor = "email";

    btn_delete.type = "button"
    btn_delete.innerText = "Deletar";
    btn_delete.id = "btn-delete";


    container.appendChild(br);

    container.appendChild(btn_delete);
    container.appendChild(input);   
    container.appendChild(label);


    document.getElementById("btn-delete").onclick = function () {deleteEmail()};

    function deleteEmail(){
        btn_delete.remove();
        input.remove();
        br.remove();
        label.remove();
    }

}
```

Aqui tem o fiddle com o código inteiro https://jsfiddle.net/5munzeja/

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite rodrigo, tudo bem? 
O que você pode fazer é guardar estas referências no próprio DOM, seja elas por id, classes ou etc. Isso vai depender muito da forma como você vai trabalhar, e o comportamento que você deseja.
Fiz uma pequena reprodução de algo que você pode tomar como base.

```js
function deletarForm(id){
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.remove()
 }
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
 const container = document.getElementById('container');
 const newContactField = document.createElement('div');
  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.innerHTML = 'excluir';
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => deletarForm(id));

  const id = `contato-${container.childElementCount}`;
  newContactField.id = id;
  newContactField.innerHTML = `
  <input type="text" placeholder="digite aqui">
    `
  newContactField.appendChild(deleteButton);
container.appendChild(newContactField);
  
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
</div>
<button id='btn'>Adicionar novo contato</button>
```

Esta é uma das estratégias, é algo bem básico porém vai te servir.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade tem vários problemas no seu código, sendo que o primeiro é a criação de id's repetidos. Repare que atribui um `id` igual a cada botão:

```
btn_delete.id = "btn-delete";
```

Que vai fazer com que tenha vários botões na página com id's iguais, o que está errado e em algum caso fará com que a sua página não faça algumas coisas corretamente.

Para além disse você atribui os novos elementos nas variáveis locais `input`, `label`, `btn_delete` e `br` criadas com `var`, logo só consegue chegar às ultimas criadas.

A solução mais simples e que torna o html correto é atribuir classes em vez de ids, e alterar a declaração das variáveis que guardam os novos elementos para `let`:

```js
function addEmail() {
  var container = document.getElementById("box");
  
  let input = document.createElement("input");  //com let
  let label = document.createElement("label");  //com let
  let btn_delete = document.createElement("button"); //com let
  let br = document.createElement("br"); //com let

  input.type = "text";
  input.name = "email";

  label.innerText = "Email";
  label.htmlFor = "email";

  btn_delete.type = "button"
  btn_delete.innerText = "Deletar";
  btn_delete.classList.add("btn-delete"); //adicionar a classe com classList
  
  container.appendChild(br);

  container.appendChild(btn_delete);
  container.appendChild(input);
  container.appendChild(label);

  btn_delete.onclick = function() { //handler de click aplicado diretamente
     input.remove();
     label.remove();
     btn_delete.remove();
     br.remove();
  };
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
<button type="button" id="criar-input" onclick="addEmail()">Criar Novo Email</button>
```

Apenas alterei as linhas de código que tem comentários. A alteração da classe com o [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) faz com que o seu html esteja correto, mas o que faz o remover funcionar é o `let`. Isso acontece devido aos [*closures*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) que não são aplicados de forma igual ao `var` e `let`. Deve dar uma leitura no link dos *closures* para aprofundar mais sobre esse assunto.

Mantive a atribuição da classe para ser consistente com a lógica que tinha, mas da forma que o código está ela não é necessária para o remover funcionar, e é algo que pode retirar se quiser.

Claro que existem outras alternativas que não fazem uso desse pormenor, mas implicam trocar bem mais coisas no seu exemplo e algumas são mais elaboradas.
Uma alternativa simples é fazer uso de navegação no html, e para o seu exemplo poderia incluir todos os elementos num novo div, e eliminar esse div navegando pelo DOM com [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) ou [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).